# Picture is in a wrong form?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm taking pictures with OpenCV library:

```
def display_frame(self, frame, dt):
        texture = Texture.create(size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')
        texture.blit_buffer(frame.tobytes(order=None), colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')
        texture.flip_vertical()
        self.image.texture = texture
        cv2.imwrite('/home/mark/frontend/picture_taken.jpg', self.image)
        cam.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The above throws:

```
cv2.imwrite('/home/mark/frontend/picture_taken.jpg', self.image)
 TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'img'
```

I'm not including all parts of the code but the above is giving you idea what kind
of image I'm trying to write on disk. On GitHub I found that this error is usually thrown when we try to write an image that we passed in in a wrong form. In some cases this can
be solved by including `img = numpy.array(self.image)` right above the line where I write the image. However that didn't work for me.

How this can be fixed ?

Comment: It expects an image that it can read. What is the type of `self.image`?

Comment: It's a Kivy image file. `<kivy.uix.image.Image object at 0x7f28af9786d0>`

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.image.html#kivy.uix.image.Image), that is no image, but a widget that displays an image.

Comment: @NiklasMertsch  Dammit, I completely forgotten that it's just a widget and not an actual image.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is just a guess but from my own experience i think your image variable is a None type. Can you try and print out if your self.image has any value

Comment: It's not None. `<kivy.uix.image.Image object at 0x7f28af9786d0>` It's a Kivy Image object.

Comment: oo if its like that i think you need to convert your kivy object to a numpy array. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58752956/convert-a-kivy-texture-to-opencv-image. Try this code, because cv2.imwrite requires numpy array as an input